# Convert INT number in PHP

Tags: php, numbers, int

I have this number `1003636` and i need to convert in this format 1.003,636 how to convert with php, this is a dynamically numbers from rows of mysql.

Comment: Try PHP's [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), but there's no way of telling the function that the last 3 numbers are the decimals. So you need to first divide by 1000, and then use the function:

```
<?php
$n = 1003636;
$n /= 1000;
echo number_format($n, 3, ",", "."); // 1.003,636 - 3 decimals, separate thousands by . and decimals by ,
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/5ghPv)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a build in function, number_format. http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

E.G.

```
$number = 1003636;
echo number_format($number); // This would output 1,003,636
```

Worth checking out the documentation, as their are certain parameters you can pass for dealing with foreign numbers, e.g. dots instead of commas and vice verse.